# How to get the value of an enum using @Field from beanio

Tags: java, spring, bean-io

I have the mapping:

```
@Field(at = 123, length = 2, required = true)
private AccountStatus accountStatus;
```

And the Enum

```
public enum AccountStatus {
CURRENT("11"),
CLOSED("13"),
UNTIL_59_PASSED_DUE("71"),
UNTIL_89_PASSED_DUE("78"),
DELETE_FRAUD("DF"),
DELETE_ACCOUNT("DA");

public String value;

AccountStatus(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}
}
```

For AccountStatus.CURRENT it is generating 'CU' and I want 11 instead. How to do that configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

- override toString() in the enum class so that it returns the value of your 'value' enum variable and add the attribute `format="toString"` to accountStatus @Field annotation.

OR

- register your own TypeHandler implementation for the enum: http://beanio.org/2.1/docs/api/org/beanio/internal/util/EnumTypeHandler.html
  by adding the attribute `handlerClass=....` to your field configuration (@Field annotation)